# If works must follow from a genuine faith, how can a Christian still sin?

Tags: faith, works, theology

Does a Christian just temporarily stop believing that Jesus died and rose again every time they sin or something?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is fairly simple: faith is not some token that you either possess or don't possess.  Good works are the fruit of exercising genuine faith, and much like physical exercise, this implies varying degrees of strength.

Paul mentions people who are "weak in faith" twice in Romans, and "strong in faith" once.  Jesus told Peter three times to "feed my sheep", implying that even those who had been converted to the Gospel require spiritual nourishment for further growth.  And who can forget the worried but hopeful father who said to Jesus, "Lord, I believe; help thou my unbelief"?  He had some degree of faith that the miracle worker he had heard tales of could help his child — if not, he would not have come to Jesus in the first place — but even so his faith was still far from perfect, and both he and Jesus recognized this.

People who lapse into sin don't stop believing for the moment, so much as they stop *caring* or stop *trying* for the moment, for whatever reason.  Or perhaps they simply don't understand how the principles of the Gospel apply to the thing they're doing, and so end up getting it wrong out of ignorance, because their faith and their spiritual maturity has not yet progressed to the appropriate level.

Comment: ...or, they simply *aren't perfect* and *can't* stop themselves every time. If, say, a basketball player misses a shot, is it (necessarily) because they stopped caring or trying? Especially if the player isn't very skilled (c.f. one "weak in faith")?

Answer (score 1):

Sin, as you have surmised, is antithetical to faith.

Faith is clearly more than a passive belief:

> Thou believest that there is one God; thou doest well: the devils also believe, and tremble. (James 2:19)

The devils also do not have faith in Christ. Surely there is at least one missing ingredient:

"Faith without works is dead." (James 2:20)

In other words, there is no such thing as faith without righteous works, and sin is the opposite of righteous works, being the work of unrighteousness.

Faith is often spoken of as hope:

> Now faith is the substance of things hoped for, the evidence of things not seen. For by it the elders obtained a good report. Through faith we understand that the worlds were framed by the word of God, so that things which are seen were not made of things which do appear. (Hebrews 11:1-3)

> faith is not to have a perfect knowledge of things; therefore if ye have faith ye hope for things which are not seen, which are true. (Alma 32:21)

"Hope" in these verses is better understood in modern vernacular as assurance, or earnest expectation (see Romans 8:19).

> faith is the **assurance** which men have of the existence of things which they have not seen; and the principle of **action** in all intelligent beings. ([Lectures on Faith](https://lecturesonfaith.com/1/) 1:9)

This isn't merely a wishy-washy or idle longing for something to be true; it does necessitate firm belief; it can only be evidenced by action in agreement with the principle we expect is true:

> I will shew thee my faith by my works. (James 2:18)

A person might still believe in the resurrection of Christ while in the act of sinning, but the act of sinning is incongruous with such belief and testimony, and therefore the person bears the witness that he is willfully rebelling against light and truth, which is what darkens the person's understanding and knowledge and condemns him if he does not repent.
This is why the prophets always taught us to repent, so that we might be cleansed and forgiven of our sins on conditions of repentance, through the merits and mercy of Jesus Christ:

> Him hath God exalted with his right hand to be a Prince and a Saviour, for to give repentance to Israel, and forgiveness of sins. Acts 5:31

Thanks and glory be to God for the priceless gift of repentance, that the sinner might be restored through a change of heart, mind and action through the grace of Jesus Christ, and be enabled to live in the presence of God forever!

> For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.
> For God sent not his Son into the world to condemn the world; but that the world through him might be saved. (John 3:16-17)

Comment: +1 to keep this more of a general answer I might remove Alma quote (as this isn't scripture recognized by other denominations).

Comment: @depperm The question pertains to Christians and as a Christian, this is a valid reason and part of an explanation. Many Christians believe what is written in the Book of Mormon and simply do not realize it yet.

Answer (score 0):

A living believer is still trapped in their sin-nature flesh until death.  Paul describes the battle that dwells within him of doing that which is wrong, when he knows perfectly well the right thing to do, but cannot find the way "to perform that which is good":

**Romans 7:14-25**

> For we know that the law is spiritual: but I am carnal, sold under sin.
> 15 For that which I do I allow not: for what I would, that do I not; but what I hate, that do I.
> 16 If then I do that which I would not, I consent unto the law that it is good.
> 17 Now then it is no more I that do it, but sin that dwelleth in me.
> 18 For I know that in me (that is, in my flesh,) dwelleth no good thing: for to will is present with me; but how to perform that which is good I find not.
> 19 For the good that I would I do not: but the evil which I would not, that I do.
> 20 Now if I do that I would not, it is no more I that do it, but sin that dwelleth in me.
> 21 I find then a law, that, when I would do good, evil is present with me.
> 22 For I delight in the law of God after the inward man:
> 23 But I see another law in my members, warring against the law of my mind, and bringing me into captivity to the law of sin which is in my members.
> 24 O wretched man that I am! who shall deliver me from the body of this death?
> 25 I thank God through Jesus Christ our Lord. So then with the mind I myself serve the law of God; but with the flesh the law of sin.

Paul in chapter 6 explains that just because we are now under God's grace, and no longer condemned for our occasional failures with sin, God's grace is by no means a license for the believer to openly sin.  Removing the sin-nature from our lives after salvation should be the goal of every believer.  The truth is that because of who we are (born of Adam and into that sin-nature) we will by nature struggle with changing our lives to follow after the Spirit and no longer our carnal flesh.

**Romans 6:14-18**

> For sin shall not have dominion over you: for ye are not under the law, but under grace.
> 15 What then? shall we sin, because we are not under the law, but under grace? God forbid.
> 16 Know ye not, that to whom ye yield yourselves servants to obey, his servants ye are to whom ye obey; whether of sin unto death, or of obedience unto righteousness?
> 17 But God be thanked, that ye were the servants of sin, but ye have obeyed from the heart that form of doctrine which was delivered you.
> 18 Being then made free from sin, ye became the servants of righteousness.

**Romans 8:1**

> There is therefore now no condemnation to them which are in Christ Jesus, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit.

**1 Thessalonians 5:19**

> Quench not the Spirit.

Understanding who we are (sinners by nature, not sinners because of our sins) helps in seeing that it is not **our** righteousness or lack thereof that we place our faith in.  It is accepting our inability to be of God's required righteousness.  We then **place our faith in Jesus Christ** being our righteousness **on our behalf** due to our incapability of this as a human.  When we possess this 'saving faith' in Christ, God's righteousness is then imputed unto us (**2 Cor 5:21**).  Our position with God then changes from being the lost sinner to that of being 'in Christ'.  God no longer sees who we see when we look into a mirror.  God now sees Christ in us and us in Christ (**1 Corinthians 1:30**, **Colossians 1:27**).

**Romans 10:3**

> For they being ignorant of God's righteousness, and going about to establish their own righteousness, have not submitted themselves unto the righteousness of God.

**2 Corinthians 11:3**

> But I fear, lest by any means, as the serpent beguiled Eve through his subtilty, so your minds should be corrupted from the simplicity that is in Christ.

Comment: @ Mark Vestal - This answer begins well in answering "how" one sins _after_ he becomes a Christian. However, the listing of verses towards the end don't really deal with this topic asked.  Your later comments are good but don't help  elucidate the problem raised. Keep studying the Bible; it'a great for the soul!  Peace

Comment: Thank you @raygrant!  Yes, I might have taken a smidge of liberty there in the end, but it is sound doctrine!  Thanks again...I'll be more careful going forward.